# PHP unset() equivalent in python

Tags: php, python, django

I am doing a django project based from a php file. In the php file it has thos kind pf code :

```
unset($_POST["nameSub"]);
```

what is the equivalent code on it using python?

Comment: it's hard to imagine why you would ever want to unset (in python: `del`) a key from the POST data

Answer (score 8):

In Django your POST data will come into your view function as `request.POST`

This is a Django `QueryDict` object and it is immutable, so you cannot remove any key from it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict

You can copy it and then remove the key from the copy:

```
post_data = request.POST.copy()
del post_data['nameSub']
```

Comment: is there any way that the `request.POST['nameSub']` will be deleted in the POST request? not in the copy?

Comment: You would be more likely to get the answer you need if you explained _why_ you want to delete a key from the post data. Because probably you are trying to do something which doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using a dictionary in Python, so:

```
d = {'nameSub': 'some value', 'another': 'value'}
del d['nameSub']
```